# Тире или запятая при уточнении

Tags: уточнения

*После полного выгорания готовый продукт () древесный уголь () выкапывался из под глины*

Какими знаками нужно выделить "древесный уголь": тире или запятая? Какая будет разница?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Нужно выделить тире.

Розенталь:
Тире для выделения (отделения) обособленных приложений употребляется, если приложение имеет пояснительный характер и перед ним можно без изменения смысла вставить слова *а именно* или *то есть*. Например:
*Я не слишком люблю это дерево — осину* (Тургенев).
*Автор описывает родину валунов, находимых даже на Украине, — Финляндию.

В парусном флоте вице-адмирал командовал авангардом — передовой частью сил — и являлся заместителем командующего флотом — адмирала.

Артиллерийская или пулеметная установка, у которой подвижная часть станка — тумба — крепится к палубе корабля, называется тумбовой установкой.

Другое отравляющее вещество — дифосген — представляет собой жидкость.

Тросы пеньковые изготовляются из лубяного растения — пеньки — и выделываются бельные и смоленые.

Ловили рыбу бреднем — маленьким неводом — да вершами-ловушками.

Я вынул из сумки глубомер — гирьку на длинной бечевке — и промерил глубину.*

В таких случаях можно задать вопрос "*а что это такое?*" или "*что за ... ?*" (*а что за готовый продукт?*).

Когда нет цели пояснить, используются запятые. Тогда даётся дополнительная информация (без неё можно обойтись):
*После полного выгорания древесный уголь, готовый продукт, выкапывался из под глины.*

**Update:**
Не стоит путать эту тему со вставкой. Это разные темы.
Так когда же нет цели пояснить? Например, если читающий в курсе, что имеется в виду древесный уголь, ему просто напоминают, или когда он догадывается об этом. Ещё если не дают нормальное определение предмету, а просто сообщают факт о нём через приложение (*древесный уголь, готовый продукт, ...*). В таких случаях здесь могут быть запятые. В примерах Розенталя с тире там обычно такое, что не догадаешься.
Запятые чаще всего используются, когда надо сообщить, как зовут человека или кто он такой.
Тире ставят, когда нужно объяснить, что это такое.
В обоих случаях (запятые или тире) информация дополнительная. Здесь важен не тип информации, а необходимость пояснить, как сказано у Розенталя.
В случае с тире дополнительная информация важна для понимания текста.
Когда в приложении напрямую называется предмет, тире больше подходят.
Какая ещё закономерность: у Розенталя в примерах с запятыми говорится про человека, а в примерах с тире — про предмет. Имеет место такая традиция.

Comment: О! Привет-привет!

Comment: Привет! Хм, странно, комментарии заработали. Раньше не работали, как у вас. Я в ответе за свои ответы, пришлось дописать, чтобы не подумали, что чего-то там "не различаю".

Answer (score 1):

1. В предложении **данной структуры** желательно использовать тире:
   *После полного выгорания готовый продукт   **– древесный уголь** –  выкапывался из-под глины.*

В этом случае приложение четко выделено увеличенными паузами. Так обозначается дополнительная информация.

2. При обособлении запятыми  уточнение «древесный уголь»  интонационно входит в первую фразу:  «После полного выгорания готовый продукт, **древесный уголь**, //  выкапывался из-под глины».  Такое произношение здесь неудобно, так как приложение фактически не отделяется паузой от существительного.

В других же случаях обособление запятой возможно, так как семантика при разных способах примерно одинакова.

3. Что касается **семантического анализа** при выборе знака, то здесь нужно учитывать следующее. Общая схема решения такова: автор с учетом семантики по контексту подбирает структуру предложения, а уже затем делает выбор знаков.

А вот редактор работает уже с готовой **структурой,** и это для него главный ориентир. Тире подходит для одной структуры, а запятые – для другой.

Comment: Тире там потому, что можно вставить слово "это". Вы правы, интонация отличается, но ссылаться только на это не вариант, потому что это не объяснить, если не записать своим голосом произношение. С запятыми не сильно новость, что то древесный уголь, это либо было известно (напоминание), либо предполагалось.

Comment: В этом ответе одно из моих открытий, в том числе и для самого себя. Но эти открытия никому не нужны, не верят, здесь ценят, когда "отвечает" Розенталь, Лопатин. Вывод: от себя ничего не добавлять, этому никто не верит, нет по ссылке — молчи. Больше всего раздражает, когда никак не реагируют те, кто спрашивал, как здесь.

Comment: oleedd,  к сожалению, мы с вами перестали понимать друг друга. Вы сдаете интонационные позиции, а ваш метод (здесь вставим, а здесь уберем) неприемлем для меня. Кстати, я тоже писала этот ответ без особой надежды на чье-либо понимание – наверное, какому-то далекому другу из будущего. Поэтому не огорчайтесь, важно хотя бы то, что мы сами себя понимаем. А вот оригинальность и самостоятельность вашего мышления я ценила всегда. Живая мысль – это лучшее, что есть в нас, даже когда мы в чем-то заблуждаемся. Высшие силы любят нас за ошибки больше, чем тех, кто правильно цитирует Розенталя и только.

Comment: Умеете вы красиво писать. Последнее предложение понравилось. Так мои выводы основаны на словах Розенталя ("если приложение имеет пояснительный характер"). Слово "это" человек не скажет, если не хочет сделать пояснение. *Кстати, я тоже писала этот ответ без особой надежды на чье-либо понимание* — такое употребление "тоже" — распространённая ошибка, я писал ответ с уверенностью, что будет галочка, ведь основан он на правиле Розенталя.

Comment: Как-то этот ответ прошёл мимо меня...

Comment: Александр, а чем этот ответ вас сейчас привлек? Вот и oleedd  пришлось вспомнить... и  грустно стало.  Как-то не вписался он в коллектив, изменился очень, вот и дружба кончилась. А друзей и так мало.

Comment: Просто просматривал сейчас вопросы Liads1, и вижу, что нет моего треугольника. Интересно то, что вы с oleedd противоположные точки зрения о дополнительной информации: у вас она обрамляется тире, а у него запятыми. Я же думаю, что то или иное выделение уточнений и пояснений далеко не всегда связано с их статусом. Вот в скобках да, дополнительная. Семантика и контекст, о которых вы говорите в пункте 3, как раз и дадут представление об основной или сопутствующей информации.

Comment: @Александр Стрелец
 Александр, я подробно изложила свое мнение во втором ответе (мне показалось, что так удобнее).

Answer (score 1):

Ответ второй (на комментарий) от 30.05.2022

О дополнительной, пояснительной и уточняющей **информации и о выборе знаков** для обособления оборота в середине предложения (запятые, тире, скобки)

1. **Разные мнения** у меня с oleedd вот почему. Он не различает (1) те предложения, где в первой части есть слова (обычно местоимения), **требующие пояснения** (раскрытия содержания) и (2) предложения, где **нет необходимости** в пояснении (она дается только как дополнительная информация).
2. Я же в этом ответе при выборе знака учитывала **структуру предложения**, а не только семантику. Дело в том, то оборот располагался как раз на месте произносительной паузы в простом предложении, поэтому запятыми его было сложно выделить (это **частный случай**, когда структура подсказывает нам решение).
3. А вот по одному предложению (без контекста) бывает с**ложно определить** статус информации (уточнение это или дополнительные сведения).

Если знаки **уже поставлены**, то мы видим, что это дополнительная информация. Если мы их **ставим сами**, то нужно или иметь контекст, или рассказать автору вопроса, как нужно выбирать вариант по семантике.

4. Что касается вашего вопроса **о тире и скобках**, то это в любом случае **вставочные знаки:** интонационно и по семантике они мало отличаются и обозначают **дополнительную информацию.** Просто статус скобок определяется как более сильный графический знак.