# Как можно объяснить это тире?

Tags: пунктуация, запятые, тире, уточнения, пояснительные

```
У него есть лишь одна роль — роль городского шута.
```

Можно ли поставить вместо тире запятую и рассматривать эту часть как уточнение?
Хочется увидеть конкретное правило.

Comment: Такое называется пояснением, а не уточнением (когда сужение понятия). Запятая здесь не подходит.

Comment: Нет. Уточнение и пояснение - это разные вещи. Даже есть отдельный параграф: "Знаки препинания при уточняющих, пояснительных и присоединительных членах предложения".

Comment: Ну да, разные. Здесь пояснение, потому что ничего не сужаем.

Comment: Тогда как объяснить тире?

Comment: Тире как раз полностью соответствует правилам, тогда как там нет ни одного примера с запятой.

Comment: Можно конкретное правило увидеть, по которому должно быть тире, на ваш взгляд?

Comment: Мне вторая часть предложения напоминает больше присоединительный член, тогда тире можно объяснить.

Comment: Лучше вместо комментария ответ оформлю тогда.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Интересно, почему возник такой вопрос – вопрос о замене тире на запятую?

*У него есть лишь одна роль, роль городского шута.*

Такая запись, на мой взгляд, нечитабельна, "некрасива", что ли. В комментариях Вы говорите о параграфе – может быть, этом:

[**XXV. Знаки препинания в предложениях с уточняющими, пояснительными и присоединительными членами предложения**](http://www.rosental-book.ru/punct_xxv.html)

> **Пояснительные члены предложения**
>
> **1.** Обособляются слова, поясняющие смысл предшествующего члена предложения. Перед пояснительным членом предложения стоят слова *а именно, то есть* (при их отсутствии в предложении **эти слова могут быть вставлены**). Например: *В то время, именно год назад, я ещё сотрудничал по журналам* (Достоевский); *Я… добрался наконец до большого села с каменной церковью в новом вкусе, т. е. с колоннами, с обширным господским домом* (Тургенев); *Ну что же, поедешь нынче вечером к нашим, к Щербацким то есть?* (Л. Толстой); *В жизни есть только одно несомненное счастье – жить для других* (Л. Толстой); *В отношениях с посторонними он требовал одного – сохранения приличия* (Герцен) (постановка тире в подобных случаях – по аналогии с пунктуацией при обособленных несогласованных определениях и приложениях.

Тире в данном предложении – и по графике, и по интонации, и по семантике, да и по правилам, в конце концов, – знак совершенно подходящий:

***У него есть лишь одна роль – роль городского шута.***

*У него есть лишь одна роль, а именно роль городского шута.*

Comment: Ну "не очень красива" как-то не очень звучит, почему же все же не запятая?

Comment: Повтор слова через запятую в данном случае – не очень :)) И я не писал "не очень красива".

Comment: "Как показывают некоторые из приведенных примеров, вместо запятой перед пояснительным членом предложения (при отсутствии пояснительного союза) часто ставится тире". Я вот здесь не вижу слова "должно".

Comment: Так и не нужно это слово "должно". Я не понимаю одного – зачем Вам эта запятая? Хотите ставьте – ничего страшного, никто не осудит. Но тире ставится по графике, по интонации, по семантике, да и по правилам, в конце концов. Хотите считайте это присоединением – так присоединение тоже может отделяться и тире, и запятой.

Comment: Это я и хотел услышать.

Comment: Вы заметили, что в первом предложении моего ответа я тоже поставил тире между словами "вопрос"? Это то же самое. Запятая там ну никак не катит. :)

Comment: @АлександрСтрелец В вашем примере запятую ещё можно (сказать вдобавок, то есть не поясняем, что за вопрос, потому все уже знают).

Comment: @oleedd Ну я и говорю, что не возбраняется постановка запятой, но "не глянется" это при повторе слова.

Comment: @АлександрСтрелец Да просто Розенталь тупанул, не в первый раз, надо было про запятую вообще не говорить, раз нет ни одного примера. Когда запятая, получается другое, расширю ответ, ваш пример помог разобраться. Здесь всё-таки одной мыслью говорим, а если запятая, то получается две мысли.

Comment: По справочнику Лопатина (он новее), только тире ставится.

Comment: Есть правило про знак после "хотите"? Вы ничего не ставите, хотя там явно условие, а не простое предложение: *Если хотите, то ставьте/считайте.*

Comment: @oleedd Да, я вчера тоже обратил на это внимание, но уже не стал удалять, исправлять и снова постить (тогда комменты были бы не по порядку). А вообще писал, как слышал, тем более после идёт тире. И [вот](https://rus.stackexchange.com/questions/445021/Всегда-ли-ставится-запятая-после-слова-хотите) вопрос Sharon на эту тему. Думаю, что запятая или тире не всегда обязательны в таких случаях.

Comment: Спросил, потому что два раза было. Но это упрощение, условие упрощать не пойдёт. Видел этот ответ. Здесь надо руководствоваться правилами и грамматикой, а не примерами. Ведь Розенталь создал свой справочник в связи с тем, что многого в правилах не было и писали по-разному, так что то, что можно встретить разные написания, никак не значит, что все правы. Это никак не сопоставимо с: *Идите/давайте ставьте/считайте.*

Answer (score 3):

Не совсем правило, но это здесь в первом пункте: http://old-rozental.ru/punctuatio.php?sid=119
Другой справочник Розенталя: https://i.stack.imgur.com/Cd56C.png
(1) Ни одного примера с запятой.

> Мне вторая часть предложения напоминает больше присоединительный член, тогда тире можно объяснить.

Да, там присоединение (но не стандартное, стандартное, когда говорится вдобавок), но запятая тоже ставится, когда присоединение, например:
*Он зайдёт к нам, завтра.*
(2) Но в данном примере запятая нарушает пояснительные отношения, которые заключаются в следующем:
*Лишь одна роль — это роль городского шута.*

(3) Как мы знаем, тире ставится вместо пропущенных слов. Здесь оно вместо пояснительных союзов. Такое (тире вместо союза) встречается в других темах.

(4) Повтор слова "роль" тоже способствует тире.

(Четыре аргумента отмечены цифрами.)

Что происходит, если поставить запятую?
Тогда цель предложения не в том, чтобы рассказать про то, что за роль (а она на самом деле в этом). Тогда нет пунктуационной и интонационной связи между частями. Получается то, что сопоставимо со следующим:
*У него есть лишь одна роль... роль городского шута.

У него есть лишь одна роль. Роль городского шута.*
Если запятая, то получаются две мысли, а не одна.

Answer (score 3):

Возьмём Академический справочник Лопатина (он новее, поэтому имеет большую силу, чем справочник Розенталя):
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]
В первых двух примерах тоже слово "один".

Если ставим запятую, то мы не поясняем (грамматически и интонационно), а говорим следующей фразой. Это соответствует разговорному стилю.

Comment: Привет от Sharon!  Вижу ваши успехи – вы вносите приятное оживление в работу форума своим нестандартным мышлением. А это от меня вопрос: по этой теме даны ответы и комментарии, но  я так и НЕ ПОНИМАЮ, можно ли ПОЯСНЕНИЕ обособлять запятыми. Розенталь говорит, что часто используется тире, но часто – это   не значит всегда. Вот предложение: «Обе девочки, Катя и Соня, стали  следить за мальчиками». Чем не пояснение?  Да и  это предложение можно записать так: «И лишь одна роль, роль городского шута, доступна для него». Позиция другая? А почему знак зависит от позиции? Если можно, очень коротко.

Comment: Приветствую! Вы были нужны, чтобы бороться с неправдой. Просто щас такое время, когда не могу заниматься своими делами. Но скоро перестану. Пару вопросов реально стоящие, что аж не жалко потраченных на ответы часов. Продолжают испытывать правила на прочность и находить слабые места, в то время как кажется, что всё уже обсуждали. Могу ответить. Розенталь виноват, что сделал не правило, а что-то расплывчатое. Когда имена, используются запятые, но не видел ни одного примера с предметами. "Обе" означает, что о них уже говорили, то есть не пояснение (когда говорим впервые), а напоминание имён.

Comment: *И лишь одна роль, роль городского шута, доступна для него* — ваш пример неестественный: в оригинальном предложении "*роль городского шута*" — самое главное, а такой структурой вы переставляете это на второй план, тогда как по смыслу оно так и остаётся самым главным. У Розенталя видел такое (тогда перелом конструкции): *И лишь одна роль, роль городского шута доступна для него.* Мне кажется, что так лучше. Когда пояснение важнее, продолжаем предложение от него.

Comment: Нужен пример с предметами?  Это легко. "Обе его причины, погода и занятость, мало чего стоят".

Comment: Где мне это применять? Ничего нет. Зачем мне это? Если не я, то вы... У меня есть примеры с вещами гораздо сложнее, но вместо этого занимаюсь относительно простыми вещами здесь. Да, позиция играет роль, но ваш пример неудачный, да даже "*роль... доступна для него*" (так не говорят, не звучит). Мой ответ абсолютно прямой. Никогда не ухожу от ответов, говорю правду, даже если она обидная. Вы ясность видите только в том, что совпадает с вашим мнением :( Имел в виду примеры в справочниках, ни одного такого нет. Здесь тоже "обе", такая же ситуация.

Comment: Видео в журнал не вставишь, у нас нет технологий, как в "Гарри Поттере". А некоторые из тех, кому мы помогаем, зарабатывают этим. Тоже не читаю, разве что на сайтах. У меня всё началось с желания писать диктанты вообще без ошибок (не получалось), чтобы получить макс. оценку, со чтением это не связано. Просто если в середине, то вставка получается, а это второй план, что не всегда подходит. Когда запятые, тоже не первый план, но оно синтаксически ближе, чем при тире, максимально близкое обособление. Но нельзя обособлять самое важное! 2 тире слишком громоздки, поэтому их не часто можно увидеть.

Comment: Нет, в "именно" (среди прочего), согласен с ними, да и они самые умные и лучшие, чтобы ошибаться. Этот ответ помните? https://rus.stackexchange.com/questions/468309 От него не отказываюсь, он верный. Просто люди обычно не верят той правде, которая оказывается неожиданной.

Comment: Ошибался даже Аристотель, в том числе в общеизвестных физических законах, поэтому критический подход к самым "умным и лучшим" никогда не помешает. А "просто люди" готовы верить всему)) И вопрос этот я  помню – наши мнения были разными, как ни странно)) Задам вам позже еще вопросик по вводному слову "по сути", там тоже интересно.

Comment: Физические законы — это законы, в которых проще всего ошибиться. Но вы же не "просто люди" в этой области, прежде всего вас имел в виду. С "по сути" вроде бы всё просто.