# Я хочу поделиться этой историей с вами (?) моими читателями

Tags: пунктуация, запятые, тире

Скажите, пожалуйста, как правильно написать это предложение?
*Я хочу поделиться этой историей с вами, моими читателями.*
Или же надо поставить тире?

Comment: Запятая, потому что не требуется пояснение местоимения.

Comment: См. мой ответ здесь: https://rus.stackexchange.com/questions/468309

Comment: Что ещё важно: при замене на творительный должно нормально звучать. Примеры из справочников: *извиваться змеёй; градом посыпаться; громом загремел; сталью засверкал; огненным дождём упали; умчится птичкой*. Это образец. Ещё помогает замена на обстоятельство, которое передаёт смысл оборота, например: *как молния* — быстро или ярко. При этом замена на творительный может не работать.

Answer (score 2):

*Моими читателями* — это распространенное приложение.
Любое приложение при личном местоимении обособляется:
*Ему ли, **карлику,** тягаться с исполином?* (Пушкин); *Вот оно, **объяснение*** (Л. Толстой).

> Вместо запятой при обособлении приложений может использоваться тире в следующих случаях:
> **1)** если перед приложением можно без изменения смысла вставить ***а именно*** (особенно если приложение стоит в конце предложения, имеет зависимые слова и внутри него уже есть знаки препинания) <...>;
> **2)** если одиночное или распространённое приложение стоит в конце предложения и при этом подчеркивается его самостоятельность или даётся разъяснение такого приложения.
> <...> *В углу гостиной стояло пузатое **бюро** на пренелепых четырёх ногах — **совершенный медведь*** (Гоголь);
> **3)** если приложение стоит в середине предложения и имеет пояснительный характер (тире ставится с двух сторон).
> *Какая-то ненатуральная **зелень — творение скучных беспрерывных дождей** — покрывала жидкою сетью поля и нивы* (Гоголь).

Но ***может** использоваться* никак не означает, что **должно** использоваться. Мне кажется, что достаточно запятой (хотя, конечно, постановка тире не возбраняется; автору — виднее).

*Я надеюсь, это не последняя встреча с персонажами и вами, **моими читателями!*** (М. Дрим); *Поэтому мне хотелось, чтобы память осталась со мной. И теперь с вами, **моими читателями*** (Е. Бочарова. Приключения в Польше. Записки волонтёра); *Рада встрече с вами, **моими читателями и друзьями*** (А. Толстоброва); *Она хотела лучшей жизни для меня, — сказал он, — я ей благодарен, а иначе я б не оказался здесь сейчас с вами, **моими друзьями*** (Саша И. Шпионы Бога).

А вот в этом предложении имеется разъяснение, и тире тут логично (не с упомянутыми участниками семинаров, а с кем-то другим, с кем именно):

*Решив контролировать свои расходы и доходы, я разработала таблицу, которой сейчас делюсь с участниками своих семинаров, а теперь и **с вами — моими читателями*** (А. Тарасова. Сам себе финансист...).

[Обособление приложений](https://licey.net/free/4-russkii_yazyk/40-kurs_russkogo_yazyka_sintaksis_i_punktuaciya/stages/718-242_obosoblenie_prilozhenii.html)

Answer (score 0):

Читающие *ваши* истории являются *вашими* читателями, и это является тождеством (*каждая мысль текста при повторении должна иметь определённое, устойчивое содержание*). Тождество в тексте обозначается знаком тире, например: «Стул — сиденье с ножками и спинкой для одного человека».

Comment: Тире, когда подлежащее и сказуемое! Здесь нет.

Comment: Правила Розенталя почитайте, когда тире ставится перед приложением и когда запятая!

Answer (score 0):

В данном случае ‟моими читателями” является приложением и одновременно пояснением. Перед приложением подобного типа, стоящим в конце, ставится тире. Вот несколько примеров из справочника Розенталя:

> Рядом помещалась каморка – хранилище каталогов (Гранин).
> Сверху проникает неутомимый гул надземной жизни – смягчённый отзвук великого труда всё побеждающих людей (Горький).
> Со слезами благодарности на глазах жители встречали Советскую Армию – освободительницу.
> В дальнем углу светилось жёлтое пятно – огонь в окне квартиры Серафимы, пристроенной к стене конюшни (Горький).

Comment: Комментарии не предназначены для расширенной дискуссии; разговор [перемещён в чат](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/142253/discussion-on-answer-by-jim-korbett--------).